# biased random walk on the natural numbers

Tags: probability, markov-chains, integers, random-walk

I want to show, that for a $\lambda$-biased random walk $(Y_k)$ on the the integers $−1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$ with probability transitions

$P(Y_{k+1}=x+1|Y_k=x)=\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$ and

$P(Y_{k+1}=x-1|Y_k=x)=\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}$

the probability that $(Y_k)$, starting from $0$ and never hits $−1$ is more than $1 − λ$.

The tip is: Markov property.

But i don’t know how to use the markov property for this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards!

Comment: There's basically two ways I know to do this kind of problem. One is to find the probability to hit $-1$ before $n>0$ and then send $n \to \infty$. This is probably not what you are meant to do here. The other is to say that the probability to ever net-move one step left is the probability to move left, plus the probability to ever net-move two steps times the probability to move right. Now how is the probability to ever net-move two steps related to the probability to ever net-move one step?

Comment: What are you mean by „net-move“?

Comment: "Net-move" is the same as "move in net". So when I say "ever net-move one step left" for example I mean that you ever reach the position one step to the left of where you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\lambda\in [0,1]$. First, for $n\ge 0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}_1(Y_{2n+1}=0)=\binom{2n+1}{n}\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{(1+\lambda)^{2n+1}},
$$
where $\mathsf{P}_k$ denotes the law of a random walk starting at $k$ (i.e., $Y_0=k$). Let $T_0:=\inf\{n:Y_n=0\}$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}_1(T_0= 2n+1)=\frac{1}{2n+1}\times \mathsf{P}_1(Y_{2n+1}=0),
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{P}_1(T_0<\infty)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathsf{P}_1(T_0= 2n+1)=\lambda,
$$
or $\mathsf{P}_1(T_0=\infty)=1-\lambda$.

Comment: Here's a third way, the "find the transition kernel exactly and read off the result".

Comment: Thank you very much! But how do you get that the sum is $\lambda$?

Comment: @toni_iva Write the sum as
$$
(1+\lambda)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n}\binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}\equiv (1+\lambda)R(x),
$$
where $x\equiv \lambda/(1+\lambda)^2$. Differentiating $R(x)$ w.r.t. $x$, one gets
$$
\frac{dR(x)}{dx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
Since $R(0)=0$,
$$
R(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4x}=\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda} \quad\Rightarrow\quad (1+\lambda)R(x)=\lambda.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But what is with the case that $\lambda>1$?

Comment: $\mathsf{P}_1(T_0<\infty)$ is increasing in $\lambda$. In general, one may write $\mathsf{P}_1(T_0<\infty)=1\wedge \lambda$ for any $\lambda\ge 0$.